# RegEx match (named) groups that show up in random order (Python re)

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

I'm trying to do a match of RegEx named groups (**preArgs**, **apm1Args**, **midArgs**, **apm2Args**, **postArgs**) listed in the regEx below, that appear in random order.
I'm able to match **Test String1**, but not the **Test String2** below:

I need to satisfy the following requirements:

1.
Each of the group may be **present 1 or more** (because of the leftover junk); or it's **absent** altogether...

2.
Each of the **apm1Args** and **apm2args** always appear with 1 or more -D switches in addition to unique javaagent jars.

I tried some OR (|) options, (?=) positive look ahead, but no luck and getting lost in the maze...
My Trials:

**RegEx** (available at: [RegEx listed at regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/LuGJLQ/1/))

```
^(?P<preArgs>.*)(?P<apm1Args>-javaagent:.+\/agent1\.jar\s+(?:-Dvendor1\.agent1\.\S+\s*)*)(?P<midArgs>.*)(?P<apm2Args>-javaagent:.+\/agent2\.jar\s+(?:-Dvendor2\.agent2\.\S+\s*)*)(?P<postArgs>.*)$
```

**Test String1**

```
-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=7777 -javaagent:/path1/to/agent1.jar -Dvendor1.agent1.applicationName=app123 -Dvendor1.agent1.tierName=myTier1 -Dvendor1.agent1.nodeName=myNode1 -Dvendor1.agent1.uniqueHostId=myHost1 -Xgcpolicy:gencon -javaagent:/path2/to/vendor2/agent2.jar -Dvendor2.agent2.agentProfile=/path2/to/profiles/agent2.profile -Dvendor2.agent2.customValue1=myValue2
```

**Test String2** (available at: [same RegEx with a different regex101.com link](https://regex101.com/r/Kv3VHM/2/))

```
-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=7777 -javaagent:/path2/to/vendor2/agent2.jar -Dvendor2.agent2.agentProfile=/path2/to/profiles/agent2.profile -Dvendor2.agent2.customValue1=myValue2 -javaagent:/path1/to/agent1.jar -Dvendor1.agent1.applicationName=app123 -Dvendor1.agent1.tierName=myTier1 -Dvendor1.agent1.nodeName=myNode1 -Dvendor1.agent1.uniqueHostId=myHost1 -Xgcpolicy:gencon
```

**UPDATE:**

I ended up with a 'loop-over' method in python to clean-up the 'apmArgs' group that show-up in random order or not show at all.  Following is my code snippet (also available to test at [repl.it](https://repl.it/Jyzh/10) )

```
import os, sys, re

regExArr=[
  '(?P<preArgs>.*)(?P<apmArgs>-javaagent:\s*\/\S+agent1\.jar\s+(?:-Dvendor1\.agent1\.\S+\s*)*)(?P<postArgs>.*)'
,'(?P<preArgs>.*)(?P<apmArgs>-javaagent:\s*\/\S+agent2\.jar\s+(?:-Dvendor2\.agent2\.\S+\s*)*)(?P<postArgs>.*)'
]

testStrList=[
  '-javaagent:/path1/to/agent1.jar -Dvendor1.agent1.applicationName=app123 -Dvendor1.agent1.tierName=myTier1 -Dvendor1.agent1.nodeName=myNode1 -Dvendor1.agent1.uniqueHostId=myHost1 -javaagent:/path1/to/agent1.jar -Dvendor1.agent1.applicationName=app123 -Dvendor1.agent1.tierName=myTier1 -Dvendor1.agent1.nodeName=myNode1 -Dvendor1.agent1.uniqueHostId=myHost1 -Xgcpolicy:gencon -javaagent:/path2/to/vendor2/agent2.jar -Dvendor2.agent2.agentProfile=/path2/to/profiles/agent2.profile -Dvendor2.agent2.customValue1=myValue2'
,'-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=7777 -javaagent:/path1/to/agent1.jar -Dvendor1.agent1.applicationName=app123 -Dvendor1.agent1.tierName=myTier1 -Dvendor1.agent1.nodeName=myNode1 -Dvendor1.agent1.uniqueHostId=myHost1'
,'-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=7777 -javaagent:/path2/to/vendor2/agent2.jar -Dvendor2.agent2.agentProfile=/metlife/runtime/installed/apm/profiles/csa.profile -Dvendor2.agent2.customValue1=myValue2 -javaagent:/path1/to/agent1.jar -Dvendor1.agent1.applicationName=app123 -Dvendor1.agent1.tierName=myTier1 -Dvendor1.agent1.nodeName= -Dvendor1.agent1.uniqueHostId=myHost1 -Xgcpolicy:gencon'
,'-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=7777 -Xgcpolicy:gencon'
]

newApmArgs='-javaagent:/path3/to/agent3.jar -Dvendor3.agent3.applicationName=app1234 -Dvendor3.agent3.tierName=myTier13 -Dvendor3.agent3.nodeName=myNode13 -Dvendor3.agent3.uniqueHostId=myHost13'

for i, testStr in enumerate(testStrList):

    for regEx in regExArr:

        matchedArgs = re.search(regEx,testStr)

        while matchedArgs:

          print "matchedArgs found count:", len(matchedArgs.groups())
          print "matchedArgs found:\n", matchedArgs.groups()
          #ignore any <apmArgs> group and concatenate other groups
          testStr=(matchedArgs.group('preArgs').strip()+' '+matchedArgs.group('postArgs').strip()).strip()
          #check further for leftover <apmArgs> and repeat the clean-up
          matchedArgs = re.search(regEx,testStr)

    testStrList[i] = testStr + ' ' + newApmArgs

print "cleaned up list testStrList that had Random groups of APM Args Text (now appended with 3rd type APM Args) is:\n", testStrList
```

**Output:**

```
matchedArgs found count: 3
matchedArgs found:
('-javaagent:/path1/to/agent1.jar -Dvendor1.agent1.applicationName=app123 -Dvendor1.agent1.tierName=myTier1 -Dvendor1.agent1.nodeName=myNode1 -Dvendor1.agent1.uniqueHostId=myHost1 ', '-javaagent:/path1/to/agent1.jar -Dvendor1.agent1.applicationName=app123 -Dvendor1.agent1.tierName=myTier1 -Dvendor1.agent1.nodeName=myNode1 -Dvendor1.agent1.uniqueHostId=myHost1 ', '-Xgcpolicy:gencon -javaagent:/path2/to/vendor2/agent2.jar -Dvendor2.agent2.agentProfile=/path2/to/profiles/agent2.profile -Dvendor2.agent2.customValue1=myValue2')
matchedArgs found count: 3
matchedArgs found:
('', '-javaagent:/path1/to/agent1.jar -Dvendor1.agent1.applicationName=app123 -Dvendor1.agent1.tierName=myTier1 -Dvendor1.agent1.nodeName=myNode1 -Dvendor1.agent1.uniqueHostId=myHost1 ', '-Xgcpolicy:gencon -javaagent:/path2/to/vendor2/agent2.jar -Dvendor2.agent2.agentProfile=/path2/to/profiles/agent2.profile -Dvendor2.agent2.customValue1=myValue2')
matchedArgs found count: 3
matchedArgs found:
('-Xgcpolicy:gencon ', '-javaagent:/path2/to/vendor2/agent2.jar -Dvendor2.agent2.agentProfile=/path2/to/profiles/agent2.profile -Dvendor2.agent2.customValue1=myValue2', '')
matchedArgs found count: 3
matchedArgs found:
('-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=7777 ', '-javaagent:/path1/to/agent1.jar -Dvendor1.agent1.applicationName=app123 -Dvendor1.agent1.tierName=myTier1 -Dvendor1.agent1.nodeName=myNode1 -Dvendor1.agent1.uniqueHostId=myHost1', '')
matchedArgs found count: 3
matchedArgs found:
('-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=7777 -javaagent:/path2/to/vendor2/agent2.jar -Dvendor2.agent2.agentProfile=/metlife/runtime/installed/apm/profiles/csa.profile -Dvendor2.agent2.customValue1=myValue2 ', '-javaagent:/path1/to/agent1.jar -Dvendor1.agent1.applicationName=app123 -Dvendor1.agent1.tierName=myTier1 -Dvendor1.agent1.nodeName= -Dvendor1.agent1.uniqueHostId=myHost1 ', '-Xgcpolicy:gencon')
matchedArgs found count: 3
matchedArgs found:
('-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=7777 ', '-javaagent:/path2/to/vendor2/agent2.jar -Dvendor2.agent2.agentProfile=/metlife/runtime/installed/apm/profiles/csa.profile -Dvendor2.agent2.customValue1=myValue2 ', '-Xgcpolicy:gencon')
cleaned up list testStrList that had Random groups of APM Args Text (now appended with 3rd type APM Args) is:
['-Xgcpolicy:gencon -javaagent:/path3/to/agent3.jar -Dvendor3.agent3.applicationName=app1234 -Dvendor3.agent3.tierName=myTier13 -Dvendor3.agent3.nodeName=myNode13 -Dvendor3.agent3.uniqueHostId=myHost13', '-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=7777 -javaagent:/path3/to/agent3.jar -Dvendor3.agent3.applicationName=app1234 -Dvendor3.agent3.tierName=myTier13 -Dvendor3.agent3.nodeName=myNode13 -Dvendor3.agent3.uniqueHostId=myHost13', '-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=7777 -Xgcpolicy:gencon -javaagent:/path3/to/agent3.jar -Dvendor3.agent3.applicationName=app1234 -Dvendor3.agent3.tierName=myTier13 -Dvendor3.agent3.nodeName=myNode13 -Dvendor3.agent3.uniqueHostId=myHost13', '-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=7777 -Xgcpolicy:gencon -javaagent:/path3/to/agent3.jar -Dvendor3.agent3.applicationName=app1234 -Dvendor3.agent3.tierName=myTier13 -Dvendor3.agent3.nodeName=myNode13 -Dvendor3.agent3.uniqueHostId=myHost13']
```

Answer (score 0):

You might find a pyparsing approach will get you going quicker then regex wrangling. Here is a parser that will process your two test strings:

```
import pyparsing as pp

# just some punctuation
COLON,EQ = map(pp.Suppress, ':=')

# expressions for key=value,... switches
subkey = pp.Word(pp.alphas)
subvalue = pp.pyparsing_common.integer | pp.Word(pp.printables, excludeChars=',')
key_value_list = pp.Dict(pp.delimitedList(pp.Group(subkey + EQ + subvalue)))

# parse switches
switch_key = pp.Word('-', pp.alphas).setParseAction(lambda t: t[0][1:].lower())
switch_value = key_value_list | subvalue
switch = switch_key + pp.Optional(COLON + switch_value)

# -D definitions
java_path_name = pp.delimitedList(pp.pyparsing_common.identifier, delim='.', combine=True)
defn = (pp.Suppress("-D") +  java_path_name.leaveWhitespace()
        + EQ.leaveWhitespace() 
        + pp.Optional(subvalue().leaveWhitespace()))

# define parser for the entire line - use Dict class to define dynamic key-value structures instead of just 2-tuples
parser = pp.Dict(pp.OneOrMore(pp.Group(defn | switch)))

tests = """\
-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=7777 -javaagent:/path1/to/agent1.jar -Dvendor1.agent1.applicationName=app123 -Dvendor1.agent1.tierName=myTier1 -Dvendor1.agent1.nodeName= -Dvendor1.agent1.uniqueHostId=myHost1 -Xgcpolicy:gencon -javaagent:/path2/to/vendor2/agent2.jar -Dvendor2.agent2.agentProfile=/metlife/runtime/installed/apm/profiles/csa.profile -Dvendor2.agent2.customValue1=myValue2
-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=7777 -javaagent:/path2/to/vendor2/agent2.jar -Dvendor2.agent2.agentProfile=/metlife/runtime/installed/apm/profiles/csa.profile -Dvendor2.agent2.customValue1=myValue2 -javaagent:/path1/to/agent1.jar -Dvendor1.agent1.applicationName=app123 -Dvendor1.agent1.tierName=myTier1 -Dvendor1.agent1.nodeName= -Dvendor1.agent1.uniqueHostId=myHost1 -Xgcpolicy:gencon
"""
parser.runTests(tests)
```

Prints:

```
-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=7777 -javaagent:/path1/to/agent1.jar -Dvendor1.agent1.applicationName=app123 -Dvendor1.agent1.tierName=myTier1 -Dvendor1.agent1.nodeName= -Dvendor1.agent1.uniqueHostId=myHost1 -Xgcpolicy:gencon -javaagent:/path2/to/vendor2/agent2.jar -Dvendor2.agent2.agentProfile=/metlife/runtime/installed/apm/profiles/csa.profile -Dvendor2.agent2.customValue1=myValue2
[['xdebug'], ['xnoagent'], ['xrunjdwp', ['transport', 'dt_socket'], ['server', 'y'], ['suspend', 'y'], ['address', 7777]], ['javaagent', '/path1/to/agent1.jar'], ['vendor1.agent1.applicationName', 'app123'], ['vendor1.agent1.tierName', 'myTier1'], ['vendor1.agent1.nodeName'], ['vendor1.agent1.uniqueHostId', 'myHost1'], ['xgcpolicy', 'gencon'], ['javaagent', '/path2/to/vendor2/agent2.jar'], ['vendor2.agent2.agentProfile', '/metlife/runtime/installed/apm/profiles/csa.profile'], ['vendor2.agent2.customValue1', 'myValue2']]
- javaagent: '/path2/to/vendor2/agent2.jar'
- vendor1.agent1.applicationName: 'app123'
- vendor1.agent1.nodeName: ''
- vendor1.agent1.tierName: 'myTier1'
- vendor1.agent1.uniqueHostId: 'myHost1'
- vendor2.agent2.agentProfile: '/metlife/runtime/installed/apm/profiles/csa.profile'
- vendor2.agent2.customValue1: 'myValue2'
- xdebug: ''
- xgcpolicy: 'gencon'
- xnoagent: ''
- xrunjdwp: [['transport', 'dt_socket'], ['server', 'y'], ['suspend', 'y'], ['address', 7777]]
  - address: 7777
  - server: 'y'
  - suspend: 'y'
  - transport: 'dt_socket'


-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=7777 -javaagent:/path2/to/vendor2/agent2.jar -Dvendor2.agent2.agentProfile=/metlife/runtime/installed/apm/profiles/csa.profile -Dvendor2.agent2.customValue1=myValue2 -javaagent:/path1/to/agent1.jar -Dvendor1.agent1.applicationName=app123 -Dvendor1.agent1.tierName=myTier1 -Dvendor1.agent1.nodeName= -Dvendor1.agent1.uniqueHostId=myHost1 -Xgcpolicy:gencon
[['xdebug'], ['xnoagent'], ['xrunjdwp', ['transport', 'dt_socket'], ['server', 'y'], ['suspend', 'y'], ['address', 7777]], ['javaagent', '/path2/to/vendor2/agent2.jar'], ['vendor2.agent2.agentProfile', '/metlife/runtime/installed/apm/profiles/csa.profile'], ['vendor2.agent2.customValue1', 'myValue2'], ['javaagent', '/path1/to/agent1.jar'], ['vendor1.agent1.applicationName', 'app123'], ['vendor1.agent1.tierName', 'myTier1'], ['vendor1.agent1.nodeName'], ['vendor1.agent1.uniqueHostId', 'myHost1'], ['xgcpolicy', 'gencon']]
- javaagent: '/path1/to/agent1.jar'
- vendor1.agent1.applicationName: 'app123'
- vendor1.agent1.nodeName: ''
- vendor1.agent1.tierName: 'myTier1'
- vendor1.agent1.uniqueHostId: 'myHost1'
- vendor2.agent2.agentProfile: '/metlife/runtime/installed/apm/profiles/csa.profile'
- vendor2.agent2.customValue1: 'myValue2'
- xdebug: ''
- xgcpolicy: 'gencon'
- xnoagent: ''
- xrunjdwp: [['transport', 'dt_socket'], ['server', 'y'], ['suspend', 'y'], ['address', 7777]]
  - address: 7777
  - server: 'y'
  - suspend: 'y'
  - transport: 'dt_socket'
```

Here is some sample code to access the parsed fields:

```
t0 = tests.splitlines()[0]
result = parser.parseString(t0)
print(result.xrunjdwp.address)
print(result['vendor1.agent1.applicationName'])
```

prints:

```
7777
app123
```

Comment: I'm using the RegEx in WebSphere CLI (wsadmin) Jython 2.1 environment; Unfortunately, pyparsing lib is not available and adding this additional library is not practical on so many WebSphere Nodes.